# VBA: emailing a range and an image

Tags: vba, email, excel, outlook

I have a report that I generate daily. This report contains about 7 charts, 1 table (just normal group of excel cells) and a number of merged cells for formatting.

I have written a nice chunk of VBA to automate this report and now I am at the bit where I wish to email this report automatically. I attempted looking on http://www.rondebruin.nl/ which seems to be normal the normal first port of call for emailing from Excel, however I can't seem to find what I am looking for.

The functionality I am trying to replicate is

- Copy range("H5:N100")
- Create new email in outlook with subject "X"
- Paste Special (Enchance Meta file or Bitmap generally gives best results)
- Send email to recipient "Y"

My problem is that I do not wish to attach the file and I need the charts. 
When converting to html i seem to lose the charts and the oddly the gradients in certain merged cells are lost.

EDIT: As requested the code I'm currently using

```
    Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Sxbdy As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object



Set SxRvSht = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")


    On Error Resume Next
    SxRvSht.Select


    Set Sxbdy = Worksheets("Report").Range("H5:N100")
      On Error GoTo 0

    If Sxbdy Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
              vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    OutApp.Session.Logon
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "EMAIL@DOMAIN.COM"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "SUBJECT!!!"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(Sxbdy)
        .display  '.send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(Sxbdy As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2010
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    'rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)

    Sxbdy.Copy
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False


    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
        SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
        Filename:=TempFile, _
        Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
        Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
        HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

My email body should in theory look like - https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwM4H.jpg
Any help would be greatly appreciated

N.B. I am currently using Excel 2007 and Outlook 2007.

Comment: Try exporting the charts images before inserting them into the email body.  Also including some of the code will give us a better idea of where errors lie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorceri's answer didn't directly solve my issue although it was a neater way of sending the email. The solution which i was looking for using the "CopyPicture method.

As such I added the Outlook reference to VBE (Tools >> References >> Microsoft Outlook 12.0 Object Library).

I then used the "CopyPicture" method to get the picture across. Splicing this into Sorceri's answer we get the below.

```
'vars
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMail As MailItem
Dim wrdEdit
'get running Outlook Application
Set oApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
'create a new email
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
'set the subject and recipient
oMail.Subject = "**PUT YOUR SUBJECT HERE**"
oMail.To = "**PUT YOUR EMAIL HERE**"
'show it
oMail.Display
'change to HTML
oMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
'get the word editor
 Set wrdEdit = oApp.ActiveInspector.WordEditor

'Copy code goes here (send keys)
Range("**PUT YOU RANGE HERE**").CopyPicture xlPrinter, xlPicture

'paste it into the email
wrdEdit.Application.Selection.Paste
oMail.Send
'release objects
Set wrdEdit = Nothing
Set oMail = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to include a reference to the Outlook object model but it is pretty straight forward.  Would have helped if you posted some code, also go get some points so you can mark your questions as answered.

```
'vars
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMail As MailItem
Dim wrdEdit
'get running Outlook Application
Set oApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
'create a new email
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
'set the subject and recipient
oMail.Subject = "Some Subject"
oMail.To = "Someone@somewhere.com"
'show it
oMail.Display
'change to HTML
oMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
'get the word editor
 Set wrdEdit = oApp.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
'get the chart and copy it
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Copy
'paste it into the email
wrdEdit.Application.Selection.Paste

'release objects
Set wrdEdit = Nothing
Set oMail = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing
```

Comment: I will attempt to add this to the code, although I'm assuming that I will need to add more to show the merged cells and formatting correctly.